# How can I query sssd via PAM in a C program?

Tags: c, pam

I'm playing around with PAM authentication using a small C program:

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_misc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    pam_handle_t* pamh;
    struct pam_conv pamc;

    pamc.conv = &misc_conv;
    pamc.appdata_ptr = NULL;
    pam_start("su", getenv("USER"), &pamc, &pamh);
    if (pam_authenticate(pamh, 0) != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Auth failed!\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Auth succeeded!\n");
    }
    pam_end(pamh, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Two kinds of users have access on my system, those created in the local shadow db, and those who traverse a configured `sssd` process to [authenticate with LDAP against a remote active directory.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LDAP_authentication#Online_and_Offline_Authentication_with_SSSD)

I've configured `sssd` to plug into PAM, which I'm able to confirm via a number of logs on the system and debug output from `sssd`, but the above program only works for local users. Users that would require authentication against `sss` get a `PAM_AUTH_ERROR` back from `pam_authenticate` whether they enter the correct credentials or not.

I'm surely missing something obvious. How can I access `sss` via PAM in a C program?

Comment: Use are using the `su` PAM service. Have you configured `/etc/pam.d/su` to use `pam_sss`?

Comment: @frasertweedale -- there we go. I changed it to the "login" service and it worked. If you post that as an answer I'll happily upvote it, otherwise I can post an answer myself.

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer.  Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

```
pam_start("su", getenv("USER"), &pamc, &pamh);
          ^^^^
```

you are using the `su` PAM service.

On a typical default configuration, the `su` PAM stack might not be configured to use the `pam_sss` responder.

Possible solutions:

- If using `su` is appropriate for your application, update `/etc/pam.d/su` to use `pam_sss`.
- Use a different PAM service that is already configured to use `pam_sss`; `login` for example.
- Create a dedicated PAM service for your app in `/etc/pam.d/<service-name>`